# how to display a div info under each marker using Mapbox and leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I am using mapbow with leaflet to display a map.
I want to add a div under each marker (like belo) but i didn't know how to make it.
I looked almost on all the doc of mapbox markers but I did not find it.

There is maybe a trick to add an HTML element for each marker with a specific information that will be shown when use rlaod

This is a screenshot of what am looking for :
[image]

And this is what i have :

[image]

Here is my code :

```js
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.MY_TOKEN';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
    .setView([48, 2.5], 5)  
    .addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/meruem92/cla6ktb2n001v16nw5ludpq67'));

var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

let template = `
    <h1>Yo sekai !</h1>
    <img src="images/disney.jpg" alt="" />
`
var geoJson = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [2.3484063461432183, 48.857478354732855]
        },
        "properties": {
            
        "tooltip": "totltip 1",
          "title": "Paris",
          "description": template,

          // Store the image url and caption in an array.
          'images': [
            ['https://i.imgur.com/O6QEpBs.jpg','The U.S. Capitol after the burning of Washington during the War of 1812'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/xND1MND.jpg','Ford\'s Theatre in the 19th century, site of the 1865 assassination of President Lincoln'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg','The National Cherry Blossom Festival is celebrated around the city each spring.']
          ],
          "icon": {
              "iconUrl": "images/marker-figma.svg",
              "iconSize": [20, 20], 
              "iconAnchor": [10, 25], 
              "popupAnchor": [0, -25], 
              "className": "dot"
          }
        
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-3.721208820629982, 40.72384968227116]
        },
        "properties": {
            
        "tooltip": "totltip 2",
          "title": "Mapbox",
          "description": "Spain, España",

          // Store the image url and caption in an array.
          'images': [
            ['https://i.imgur.com/O6QEpBs.jpg','The U.S. Capitol after the burning of Washington during the War of 1812'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/xND1MND.jpg','Ford\'s Theatre in the 19th century, site of the 1865 assassination of President Lincoln'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg','The National Cherry Blossom Festival is celebrated around the city each spring.']
          ],
          "icon": {
              "iconUrl": "images/marker-figma.svg",
              "iconSize": [20, 20], 
              "iconAnchor": [10, 25], 
              "popupAnchor": [0, -25], 
              "className": "dot"
          }
        
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            
        "tooltip": "totltip 3",
          "title": "Lincoln Park",
          "description": "A northside park that is home to the Lincoln Park Zoo",

          // Store the image url and caption in an array.
          'images': [
            ['https://i.imgur.com/O6QEpBs.jpg','The U.S. Capitol after the burning of Washington during the War of 1812'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/xND1MND.jpg','Ford\'s Theatre in the 19th century, site of the 1865 assassination of President Lincoln'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg','The National Cherry Blossom Festival is celebrated around the city each spring.']
          ],
          "icon": {
              "iconUrl": "images/marker-figma.svg",
              "iconSize": [20, 20], 
              "iconAnchor": [10, 25], 
              "popupAnchor": [0, -25], 
              "className": "dot"
          }
        
        },
        "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [-87.637596, 41.940403],
          "type": "Point"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            
        "tooltip": "totltip 4",
          "title": "Burnham Park",
          "description": "A lakefront park on Chicago's south side",

          // Store the image url and caption in an array.
          'images': [
            ['https://i.imgur.com/O6QEpBs.jpg','The U.S. Capitol after the burning of Washington during the War of 1812'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/xND1MND.jpg','Ford\'s Theatre in the 19th century, site of the 1865 assassination of President Lincoln'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg','The National Cherry Blossom Festival is celebrated around the city each spring.']
          ],
          "icon": {
              "iconUrl": "images/marker-figma.svg",
              "iconSize": [20, 20], 
              "iconAnchor": [10, 25], 
              "popupAnchor": [0, -25], 
              "className": "dot"
          }
        
        },
        "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [-87.603735, 41.829985],
          "type": "Point"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            
        "tooltip": "totltip 1",
          "title": "Millennium Park",
          "description": "A downtown park known for its art installations and unique architecture",

          // Store the image url and caption in an array.
          'images': [
            ['https://i.imgur.com/O6QEpBs.jpg','The U.S. Capitol after the burning of Washington during the War of 1812'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/xND1MND.jpg','Ford\'s Theatre in the 19th century, site of the 1865 assassination of President Lincoln'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg','The National Cherry Blossom Festival is celebrated around the city each spring.']
          ],
          "icon": {
              "iconUrl": "images/marker-figma.svg",
              "iconSize": [20, 20], 
              "iconAnchor": [10, 25], 
              "popupAnchor": [0, -25], 
              "className": "dot"
          }
        
        },
        "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [-87.622554, 41.882534],
          "type": "Point"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            
        "tooltip": "totltip 1",
          "title": "Grant Park",
          "description": "A downtown park that is the site of many of Chicago's favorite festivals and events",

          // Store the image url and caption in an array.
          'images': [
            ['https://i.imgur.com/O6QEpBs.jpg','The U.S. Capitol after the burning of Washington during the War of 1812'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/xND1MND.jpg','Ford\'s Theatre in the 19th century, site of the 1865 assassination of President Lincoln'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg','The National Cherry Blossom Festival is celebrated around the city each spring.']
          ],
          "icon": {
              "iconUrl": "images/marker-figma.svg",
              "iconSize": [20, 20], 
              "iconAnchor": [10, 25], 
              "popupAnchor": [0, -25], 
              "className": "dot"
          }
        
        },
        "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [-87.619185, 41.876367],
          "type": "Point"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            
        "tooltip": "totltip 1",
          "title": "Humboldt Park",
          "description": "A small park on Chicago's northwest side",

          // Store the image url and caption in an array.
          'images': [
            ['https://i.imgur.com/O6QEpBs.jpg','The U.S. Capitol after the burning of Washington during the War of 1812'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/xND1MND.jpg','Ford\'s Theatre in the 19th century, site of the 1865 assassination of President Lincoln'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg','The National Cherry Blossom Festival is celebrated around the city each spring.']
          ],
          "icon": {
              "iconUrl": "images/marker-figma.svg",
              "iconSize": [20, 20], 
              "iconAnchor": [10, 25], 
              "popupAnchor": [0, -25], 
              "className": "dot"
          }
        
        },
        "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [-87.70199, 41.905423],
          "type": "Point"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            
        "tooltip": "totltip 1",
          "title": "Douglas Park",
          "description": "A small park near in Chicago's North Lawndale neighborhood",

          // Store the image url and caption in an array.
          'images': [
            ['https://i.imgur.com/O6QEpBs.jpg','The U.S. Capitol after the burning of Washington during the War of 1812'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/xND1MND.jpg','Ford\'s Theatre in the 19th century, site of the 1865 assassination of President Lincoln'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg','The National Cherry Blossom Festival is celebrated around the city each spring.']
          ],
          "icon": {
              "iconUrl": "images/marker-figma.svg",
              "iconSize": [20, 20], 
              "iconAnchor": [10, 25], 
              "popupAnchor": [0, -25], 
              "className": "dot"
          }
        
        },
        "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [-87.699329, 41.860092],
          "type": "Point"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            
        "tooltip": "totltip 1",
          "title": "Calumet Park",
          "description": "A park on the Illinois-Indiana border featuring a historic fieldhouse",

          // Store the image url and caption in an array.
          'images': [
            ['https://i.imgur.com/O6QEpBs.jpg','The U.S. Capitol after the burning of Washington during the War of 1812'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/xND1MND.jpg','Ford\'s Theatre in the 19th century, site of the 1865 assassination of President Lincoln'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg','The National Cherry Blossom Festival is celebrated around the city each spring.']
          ],
          "icon": {
              "iconUrl": "images/marker-figma.svg",
              "iconSize": [20, 20], 
              "iconAnchor": [10, 25], 
              "popupAnchor": [0, -25], 
              "className": "dot"
          } 
        },
        "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [-87.530221, 41.715515],
          "type": "Point"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            
        "tooltip": "totltip 1",
          "title": "Jackson Park",
          "description": "A lakeside park that was the site of the 1893 World's Fair",

          // Store the image url and caption in an array.
          'images': [
            ['https://i.imgur.com/O6QEpBs.jpg','The U.S. Capitol after the burning of Washington during the War of 1812'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/xND1MND.jpg','Ford\'s Theatre in the 19th century, site of the 1865 assassination of President Lincoln'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg','The National Cherry Blossom Festival is celebrated around the city each spring.']
          ],
          "icon": {
              "iconUrl": "images/marker-figma.svg",
              "iconSize": [20, 20], 
              "iconAnchor": [10, 25], 
              "popupAnchor": [0, -25], 
              "className": "dot"
          }
        
        },
        "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [-87.580389, 41.783185],
          "type": "Point"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            
        "tooltip": "totltip 1",
          "title": "Columbus Park",
          "description": "A small park in Chicago's Austin neighborhood",

          // Store the image url and caption in an array.
          'images': [
            ['https://i.imgur.com/O6QEpBs.jpg','The U.S. Capitol after the burning of Washington during the War of 1812'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/xND1MND.jpg','Ford\'s Theatre in the 19th century, site of the 1865 assassination of President Lincoln'],
            ['https://i.imgur.com/EKJmqui.jpg','The National Cherry Blossom Festival is celebrated around the city each spring.']
          ],
          "icon": {
              "iconUrl": "images/marker-figma.svg",
              "iconSize": [20, 20],
              "iconAnchor": [10, 25],
              "popupAnchor": [0, -25],
              "className": "dot" 
        },
        "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [-87.769775, 41.873683],
          "type": "Point"
        }
      }
    ]
};
 

// Add custom popup html to each marker.
myLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    var marker = e.layer;
    // marker.bindTooltip("my tooltip text").openTooltip();

    var feature = marker.feature;
    var images = feature.properties.images
    var slideshowContent = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var img = images[i];

        slideshowContent += '<div class="image' + (i === 0 ? ' active' : '') + '">' +
                              '<img src="' + img[0] + '" />' +
                              '<div class="caption">' + img[1] + '</div>' +
                            '</div>'; 
    }

    // Create custom popup content
    var popupContent =  
    '<div id="' + feature.properties.id + '" class="popup">' +
        '<h2>' + feature.properties.title + '</h2>' +
        '<div class="slideshow">' +
            slideshowContent +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="cycle">' +
            '<a href="#" class="prev">&laquo; Previous</a>' +
            '<a href="#" class="next">Next &raquo;</a>' +
        '</div>'
    '</div>';

    // http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup
    marker.bindPopup(popupContent,{ 
        minWidth: 320
    });
    
    marker.setIcon(L.icon(feature.properties.icon));

    

  for (var i = 0, l = geoJson.features.length; i < l; i++) { 
      marker.bindTooltip("You clicked marker: " + i).openTooltip();
    console.dir(marker._tooltip._content) 
  }
});

// Add features to the map
myLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);

$('#map').on('click', '.popup .cycle a', function() {
    var $slideshow = $('.slideshow'),
        $newSlide;

    if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
        $newSlide = $slideshow.find('.active').prev();
        if ($newSlide.index() < 0) {
            $newSlide = $('.image').last();
        }
    } else {
        $newSlide = $slideshow.find('.active').next();
        if ($newSlide.index() < 0) {
            $newSlide = $('.image').first();
        }
    }

    $slideshow.find('.active').removeClass('active').hide();
    $newSlide.addClass('active').show();
    return false;
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: teal;
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  /* margin: 50px auto; */
}

.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper img,
.mapboxgl-popup-content img {
  width: 100%;
}

.marker {
  background-image: url("images/marker-figma.svg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  /* border-radius: 50%; */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mapboxgl-popup {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-content {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

/* //Popup style */
.popup {
  text-align: center;
}
.popup .slideshow .image {
  display: none;
}
.popup .slideshow .image.active {
  display: block;
}
.popup .slideshow img {
  width: 100%;
}
.popup .slideshow .caption {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}
.popup .cycle {
  padding: 10px 0 20px;
}
.popup .cycle a.prev {
  float: left;
}
.popup .cycle a.next {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <!-- <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.css"
    /> -->
     <!-- <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.2/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' /> -->
  <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.3.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <title>Map project js</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.2/mapbox-gl.js'></script> -->
    
  <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script> -->

  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.3.1/mapbox.js'></script>

    <script src="main2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it :

```
for (var i = 0; i < tooltip.length; i++) {
   marker.bindTooltip(tooltip).openTooltip();
   console.dir(tooltip);
 }
```

i added this loop under `marker.setIcon`